# Show 2 remote connections side-by-side with FileZilla?

Tags: virtualbox, ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

I am developping a website on a VM on my laptop and want to regularly upload the updates on the public server. I have been using Cyberduck to do that but the process is pretty slow.

I want to switch to another FTP client, FileZilla seems a fast option. However I'm trying to figure out how I could have the 2 remote connections side-by-side so that I can transfer files from left to right.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did it another way: installed samba on the virtual machine to mount the /var/www folder on my laptop and use this as the local site of FileZilla.